# Query $in mongoose Variable String Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got the following model:

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    msgID: String,
    patientList: [String],
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});
```

The patientList is always variable.

I'm trying to create a Mongoose query that can find all records where a given patientID falls within the patientList of a given message. This is what I'm trying, but I keep getting empty records.

```
    var patientID   = req.params.patientID;
    var query = Message.find({});

    if(patientID){
        console.log(patientID);
        query = query.where(patientID).in('patientList');
    }
```

All of the other questions I've seen asked are trying to query in an array with known values. In my case, the patientList could have any number of patientIDs.

Any ideas?

Right now I'm just getting the following output:

```
{
"name": "MongoError"
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I'm sorry if I'm posting a comment right here but I did not know how to contact you. I'm following your Making **MEAN Apps with Google Maps** tutorial for a University Project and I'm stuck with a geoSpatial query. Would you mind giving a look at this +50 Open Bounty Question I recently posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733030/finding-closest-points-to-a-certain-point-given-its-coordinates-and-maximum-dist ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Found my answer... Apparently this works:

```
query = query.where('patientList').equals(patientID);
```